# Как запустить webpack через npm скрипты?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, npm, webpack

У меня в проекте, есть несколько сайтов с кардинально разными webpack конфигами. Я хочу запускать сборку через npm start -имяСайта (т.е. передавать в npm start имя сайта в виде параметра)? Как это легче сделать? Я пытался запускать, node.js скрипт("start": "node start.js"), в котором по переданным переменным, запускать нужный конфиг webpack, но в этом случае логи webpack не выводятся в консоль, подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как то поправить?

Comment: Т.е. мне как бы хочется иметь одну команду для сборки на проекте - npm start, при этом мне хочется передать в npm start параметр, по которому будет запущен нужный конфиг webpakc - их у меня несколько для разных сайтов в проекте.